# C# PostSharp and App.Metrics cannot run together

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm facing a problem between these 2 frameworks.

How to reproduce the problem:

```
using System;

using App.Metrics;

namespace Metrics.src.Common.Interfaces
{
    //using Enumerators;

    public interface IApdex
    {
        String Name { get; set; }
        Unit MeasurementUnit { get; set; }
        Boolean AllowWarmup { get; set; }
        Double ApdexTSeconds { get; set; }
        String Context { get; set; }
        Boolean ResetOnReporting { get; set; }

        Boolean Track(Action action);
        Boolean Reset();
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unhandled exception (postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe release | .NET Framework 4.6.1): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Ambiguous assembly binding policies: Assembly 'system.runtime, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' redirects both to 'system.runtime, version=4.1.2.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'system.runtime, version=4.0.20.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyBindingPolicyManager.EvaluatePolicy(IAssemblyName assemblyName, Boolean evaluateSystemPolicies)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.^4+F3cylo(IAssemblyName _0, IAssemblyName _1, AssemblyBindingPolicyManager _2, BindingOptions _3, Boolean _4)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.^nQbUijLO(String _0, IAssemblyName _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindType(Type reflectionType, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.DeclarationCache.^pFnf8wEt()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.get_TypeIdentifier()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.CompareExtensions.DefinitionMatchesReference(INamedType definition, INamedType reference, BindingOptions options)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.^A9yFoe2uB3TC(ITypeSignature _0, BindingOptions _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.MatchesReference(ITypeSignature reference)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.CustomAttributeDeclarationCollection.Contains(IType type)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^SgrhoGlQ(AssemblyRefDeclaration _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^+GwnKh4ZYHu3()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation). Metrics
```

Is there any way to get these 2 guys working together? Anyone faced this before?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please try with PostSharp 5.1 and report the result. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works but, any plans for a release package? Today is still on 5.1.1 alpha version. By company policies, we cannot publish anything that's not production. any dates? So, thanks for your answer, it really helped me.

Comment: We never publish dates. All I can say is that getting 5.1 RTM is our priority.